# How to get the next not filtered row number (one down from current row) in Google Sheets with script?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-sheets, spreadsheet, setvalue

I want to set the value (next not filtered row number) in A1. With the function isRowHiddenByFilter I experienced in another context that it took up to 15 seconds. Hopefully the execution will be faster.

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

function a() {
  var x = s.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  for(y = 1; s.isRowHiddenByFilter(x); ++y);
  s.getRange('A1').setValue(x);
}
```

next way I've tried that does not work

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

function a() {
  var lastColumn = s.getActiveRange().getLastColumn();
  var x = s.getActiveRange().offset(1, -lastColumn+1).getValue();
  var y = s.getRange('D1').setValue(x);
}
```

Formula of D1

```
=MATCH(D1, A:A, 0)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `How to get the next not filtered row number (one down from current row) in Google Sheets with script?`. So at first, I would like to correctly understand about your goal. In your situation, the basic filter is used to the sheet, and for example, under this condition, when the rows of "Row1", "Row2", "Row4", "Row5", "Row7" are shown, you want to retrieve the row 4. And also, you want to reduce the process time of the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: For example, if the current cell is in row 5 and rows 6 to 9 are not displayed because they are filtered, then the next visible row below is row 10. When I run the macro and I am in row 5, I want row number 10 to be inserted in D1 (getValue, setValue). I need the value to see in which row it continues (index).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm whether my understanding is correct. When the rows 1 to 8 have the values and the rows of "Row1", "Row2", "Row4", "Row5", "Row7", "Row8" are shown, you want to retrieve the number of 7. And, you want to put `7` to the cell "D1". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If the active cell is in "Row5" and "Row6" is filtered, but "Row7" not, then 7 has to set in D1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code snippet you shared, you are checking whether the currently selected row is hidden by a filter in **every iteration** of the `for` loop. You should check a different row in each iteration, so you should use the loop index.

For example, you could do this:

```js
function nextNotFilteredRow() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = s.getCurrentCell().getRow() + 1;
  for (var i = startRow; i <= s.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if (!s.isRowHiddenByFilter(i)) {
      s.getRange('A1').setValue(i);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isRowHiddenByFilter(Integer))

Comment: I only need one value (row number of next visible row viewed from the row of the active cell). How can this be changed so that only this one value is inserted once? I have noticed that it happens several times.

Comment: @user8652270 The `return` was missing. I fixed that and now it should stop execution when the first non-hidden row is found. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @user8652270 Also I fixed a small typo (loop should finish when `i <= s.getLastRow()`, otherwise last row would be ignored).